# AppBarLayout and Google maps fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am facing a problem with adding Google maps fragment when AppBarLayout is used. Please help, this is the code with commented fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:id="@+id/main_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!--<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:cameraZoom="16"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />-->

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/location_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/time_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/distance_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/nav_view"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
  app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried to move the fragment up and down and put it in every layout I know, but noting worked. Will be very thankful if you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. I found solution :D
Here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:cameraZoom="16"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" /> 
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   android:id="@+id/main_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
           android:id="@+id/location_fab"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_location" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/time_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/distance_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/nav_view"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
  app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is this:

Remove the fragment element from the drawerlayout and move it to the actual fragment or activity that you will load when a user selects a given item in the drawer.

So, if you place the map fragment in its own layout file and inflate that layout in its own Fragment and then finally set the fragment appropriately when a user selects MAP for example from the drawer!

I hope this helps. Good luck!